# Keras Transfer learning with Resnet50 fail with Exception

Tags: keras, keras-layer, resnet

I am using Resnet50 to do transfer learning. The backend is tensorflow.
I tried to stack three more layers on top of the Resnet but fail with following error:

```
Exception: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, None, 2048). 
Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.
```

The code for stacking two models are as following:

```
model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

model = Model(input=model.input, output=top_model(model.output))
```

Answer (score 1):

The last layer of resnet with include_top=False option is already flattened and you don't need another flattening layer.

Comment: Are you sure? https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/89e6eb01f200ef6fa8db926ecfee68b37b229fbc/keras/applications/resnet50.py#L234

Comment: I'm following the same example, seems like you don't need to flatten to compile, but later I had issues and opted to specify the input_shape to resnet. And _then_ I did need to Flatten in order to train.

Answer (score 1):

You must explicit input_shape when instantiate of the Resnet.

`model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3))`

In case you have theano as backend you must set the number of channel as  first:

`model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(3,224,224))`